# IVY Error while compiling Angular v8 project with Kendo

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, angular8, angular-ivy, kendo-angular-ui

I updated my project Angular version from v7 to v8. Kendo libraries are used in my project. When I enabled Ivy for compilation, I am getting following error.

[image]

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "portal",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "author": "XXXx",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max-old-space-size=4201 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve  --port 1234 --live-reload=false",
    "build": "node --max-old-space-size=4201 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@agm/js-marker-clusterer": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^5.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^4.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^4.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.1",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.5.12",
    "@progress/kendo-file-saver": "^1.0.7",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^4.0.0",
    "@swimlane/dragula": "^3.7.3",
    "@swimlane/ngx-dnd": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/arcgis-js-api": "^4.10.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.43",
    "@types/dhtmlxscheduler": "^4.3.36",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.13",
    "@types/jquery": "3.3.30",
    "ang-jsoneditor": "^1.6.2",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^3.0.2",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "angular2gridster": "^8.0.1",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "ap-angular-fullcalendar": "^1.7.10",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "3.1.4",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "dhtmlx-scheduler": "^5.1.6",
    "esri-loader": "^2.9.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "jsoneditor": "^6.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "luxon": "^1.12.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-validation": "4.2.0",
    "ngc-float-button": "^1.2.1",
    "ngx-avatar": "^3.7.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "12.2.0",
    "ngx-facebook": "2.4.0",
    "ngx-gallery": "^5.9.0",
    "ngx-mask": "8.0.1",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "4.0.0",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.1.0",
    "ngx-owl-carousel": "2.0.7",
    "ngx-pipes": "^2.4.6",
    "ngx-popover": "0.0.16",
    "ngx-rating": "0.0.9",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.801.0",
    "@angular/cli": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.13",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.119",
    "@types/node": "^12.6.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.0",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "del": "^5.0.0",
    "git-semver-tags": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-bump": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-conventional-changelog": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-flatten": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-hub": "^4.2.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-merge-json": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.7.0",
    "gulp-tag-version": "^1.3.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "js-marker-clusterer": "^1.0.0",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "rxjs-tslint-rules": "^4.8.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Support for Ivy is still a work in progress as of October 29 2019: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/2321